# Missing required parameters for [Route: employees.update] laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i am creating crud in laravel.i ran into the problem with Missing required parameters for [Route: employees.update] [URI: employees/{employee}]. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\jbs\resources\views\employees\edit.blade.php)what i tried so far i attach below. i added the model view controller below

**Edit Blade Page**

```
  @extends('employees.layout')       
    @section('content')
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 margin-tb">
                <div class="pull-left">
                    <h2>Edit Employee</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="pull-right">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('employees.index') }}"> Back</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
       
        @if ($errors->any())
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <strong>Whoops!</strong> There were some problems with your input.<br><br>
                <ul>
                    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                        <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            </div>
        @endif
      
        <form action="{{ route('employees.update',$employees->id) }}" method="POST">
            @csrf
            @method('PUT')
       
             <div class="row">
    
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <strong>StudentName:</strong>
                        <input type="text" name="name" value="{{ $employees->studname }}" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
                    </div>
                </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <strong>Course</strong>
                                    <input type="text" name="name" value="{{ $employees->course }}" class="form-control" placeholder="course">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <strong>Fee</strong>
                                                <input type="text" name="name" value="{{ $employees->fee }}" class="form-control" placeholder="fee">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 text-center">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
       
        </form>
    @endsection
```

**Controller**

```
 public function edit(Employee $employees)
    {
        return view('employees.edit',compact('employees'));
    }



    public function update(Request $request, Employee $employees)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'studname' => 'required',
            'course' => 'required',
            'fee' => 'required',
        ]);

        $employees->update($request->all());

        return redirect()->route('employees.index')
            ->with('success','Employee updated successfully');
    }
```

**Model**

```
    protected $fillable = [
        'studname', 'course','fee',
    ];
}
```

[image]

**routes**

```
Route::resource('employees','App\Http\Controllers\EmployeeController');
```

Comment: Do you get the error after you submit or when you load the page? if you can still load the page you can try to inspect the action attribute. by the way the second parameter of the route helper must be an array, so you should write it like this  `route('employees.update', [$employees->id])`

Comment: Still my problem is not solved i tried 2 days still the same problem i tried all the ways

Answer (score 0):

Your route parameter is `employee` not `employees`. Route parameter names for resource routes are **singular** by default. The route is actually like this:

```
employees/{employee}
```

So in your `edit` method of your Controller you are using the wrong parameter name so you are getting a new instance of Employee instead of the Implicit Route Model Binding that would inject the instance based on the route parameter, you need to match the typehinted parameter name to the route parameter name:

```
//                            {employee}
public function edit(Employee $employee)
{
    ...
    return view(...., ['employee' => $employee]);
}
```

Now in the view you will have your actual existing Employee instance that you can use to generate the URL to the route instead of an empty Employee that does not have an `id` which was returning `null`:

```
{{ route('employees.update', ['employee' => $employee->id]) }}
// or
{{ route('employees.update', ['employee' => $employee]) }}
```

The route system can get the correct key from the model instance.

Comment: Still my problem is not solved i tried 2 days still the same problem i tried all the ways

Comment: @tutusfun did you make these changes?

Comment: yes still have a problem. can i send the project to you pls help

Answer (score -1):

You should pass $employees->id as a hidden input field.

Make your route as

```
 Route::post('employee/update', 'YourController@yourFunction');
```

and in the edit page the form action should look like

```
<form action="{{ route('employees.update'}}" method="POST">
```

make a hidden input field for passing id

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$employees->id}}"></input>
```

Comment: Route::post('employee/update', 'App\Http\Controllers\EmployeeController'); if i write i got the error on routes i already add Route::resource('employees','App\Http\Controllers\EmployeeController');

Comment: then do not create the route, and if you add a hidden input for passing id, then you do not need to pass $employees->id parament in form's update action.

Comment: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ')' (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\jbs\resources\views\employees\edit.blade.php)  eror displayed i changed <form action="{{ route('employees.update'}}" method="POST">
 and  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$employees->id}}"></input>
like i exapled above\

Comment: a bracket was missing, use these in action.
{{ route('employees.update')}}

Comment: inputs are not route parameters

Comment: Still my problem is not solved i tried 2 days still the same problem i tried all the ways

Answer (score -1):

You should pass the route name to the route function like this

```
route('route name',parameter1)
```

Example :

```
Route::post('employee/update/{id}' ,YourController@update)->name('update_employee');

    <form action="{{ route('update_employee',$employees->id) }}" method="POST">
        @csrf
...
```

Comment: UnexpectedValueException

  Invalid route action: [App\Http\Controllers\EmployeeController].
Error

Comment: change YourController to EmployeeController

Comment: and make your update function like this
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
....

Comment: i see you set meethod post and override it to put using @ 
        <form action="{{ route('employees.update',$employees->id) }}" method="POST">
            @csrf
            @method('PUT')
 remove put

Comment: Missing required parameters for [Route: employees.update] [URI: employees/{employee}]. (View

Comment: Route::resource('employees', 'EmployeesController');
no need to full path

Comment: Still my problem is not solved i tried 2 days still the same problem i tried all the ways

Comment: try to use the route as I do instead of using the resource and update your form same as me